# How to use AsyncLayoutInflater with Kotlin coroutines without blocking UI

Tags: android, kotlin, layout-inflater, kotlinx.coroutines

I've written this extension function which suits my needs:

```
suspend fun AsyncLayoutInflater.inflateSuspended(@LayoutRes resid: Int, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
    return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        inflate(resid, parent) { view, _, parent ->
            continuation.resume(view)
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure how I should use it without blocking UI. I tried Dispatchers.IO but I got *RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()*

How should I use this function?

**Update:** I discovered that `inflate` doesn't freeze the UI but addView does. `calendarHolder` is inside a `ScrollView`. Scrolling freezes right before calendarView is shown in the screen.

```
val inflater = AsyncLayoutInflater(this)

val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
coroutineScope.launch {
    val startTimeInside = System.currentTimeMillis()
    repeat(100) {
        calendarView = inflater.inflateSuspended(R.layout.layout_calendar, calendarHolder)
                as MaterialCalendarView
    }

    val addViewStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
    calendarHolder.addView(calendarView)

    val endTimeInside = System.currentTimeMillis()

    Timber.i("inflate: ${endTimeInside - startTimeInside}")
    Timber.i("addView: ${endTimeInside - addViewStart}")

    setupCalendar()
}

val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

Timber.i("outside: ${endTime - startTime}")
```

Even if log shows this:

outside: 2
inflate: 2105
addView: 5

Comment: By definition, it won't block the UI, so why you need a coroutine? `AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener` will be execute on the `mainThread` asynchronously

Comment: Right now, I'm inflating a calendar and in `OnInflateFinishedListener ` I make a network request to fill the events of that calendar. I'm planning to use async await on them.

Comment: Do not make a blocking network request directly from the listener. Once you've set this up as a coroutine, make the network call inside a `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` block. This is not the same as launching the entire coroutine in `IO`.

Comment: @osrl I updated to answer to make a network request using **Volley** and include a delay of one second to show that the UI is never blocked

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik but it's already what I'm doing. Actually, If I was making a network call inside the callback it would throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 1):

Like I mentioned in my comment, `AsyncLayoutInflater` is by definition asynchronous, and is mandatory to create the instance in the main thread, that's why you get an error if you change the `Dispatcher`. Nevertheless, it is possible to convert the callback-style to a coroutine style.

**Example: updated to show the composition of coroutines**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {

    private val activityJob = Job()
    private lateinit var requestQueue: RequestQueue

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + activityJob

    suspend fun AsyncLayoutInflater.inflate(@LayoutRes resid: Int, parent: ViewGroup?): View =
        suspendCoroutine { continuation -> inflate(resid, parent) { view, _, _ -> continuation.resume(view) } }

    suspend fun getTodo(id: Int): String = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
        val request =  StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/$id",
            Response.Listener { continuation.resume(it) },
            Response.ErrorListener { continuation.resumeWithException(it) }
        )
        requestQueue.add(request)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        val parent = findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.frameLayout)
        val asyncLayoutInflater = AsyncLayoutInflater(this)

        launch {
            val view = asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.async_layout, parent) as TextView
            parent.addView(view)

            delay(1000)

            val todo = getTodo(1)
            view.text = todo
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        activityJob.cancel()
        requestQueue.cancelAll { true }
    }
}
```

[More information](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/coroutines.md#wrapping-callbacks)

Comment: I've tried this, but it blocked the main thread. There is an obvious freeze on ui. Using `Dispatchers.Main` makes it run on main thread I assume.

Comment: Of course it makes the coroutine run on the main thread, that's the point. But it doesn't make the layout inflation run on the main thread. BTW the documentation clearly states that you should never `GlobalScope.launch` coroutines. Make your activity implement `CoroutineScope` and this will at the same time improve your code: you won't have to explicitly specify `Dispatchers.Main`.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing. Did you run this on an actual device? Also inflating textview won't take much time. Try to inflate a very complex view. Like https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview in my case

Comment: `inflate` function should switch thread and return to the main thread. But main thread freezes with this. Try to run inflate multiple times to see better